# EventMachine with em-synchrony I need to correctly throttle my http requests

Tags: ruby, http, asynchronous, eventmachine, fibers

I have a consumer which pulls messages off of a queue via an evented subscription. It takes those messages and then connects with a rather slow http interface.  I have a worker pool of 8 and once those are all filled up I need to stop pulling requests from the queue and have the fibers that are working on the http jobs keep working.  Here is an example I've thrown together.

```
def send_request(callback)
  EM.synchrony do

    while $available <= 0

      sleep 2 

      puts "sleeping"
    end 
    url = 'http://example.com/api/Restaurant/11111/images/?image%5Bremote_url%5D=https%3A%2F%2Firs2.4sqi.net%2Fimg%2Fgeneral%2Foriginal%2F8NMM4yhwsLfxF-wgW0GA8IJRJO8pY4qbmCXuOPEsUTU.jpg&image%5Bsource_type_enum%5D=3'
    result = EM::Synchrony.sync EventMachine::HttpRequest.new(url, :inactivity_timeout => 0).send("apost", :head => {:Accept => 'services.v1'})

    callback.call(result.response) 
  end 
end

def display(value)
  $available += 1
  puts value.inspect
end

$available = 8 

EM.run do
  EM.add_periodic_timer(0.001) do
    $available -= 1
    puts "Available: #{$available}"

    puts "Tick ..." 
    puts send_request(method(:display))
  end 

end
```

I have found that if I call sleep within a while loop in the synchrony block, the reactor loop gets stuck.  If I call sleep within an if statement(sleeping just once) then most times it is enough time for the requests to finish but it is unreliable at best.  If I use EM::Synchrony.sleep, then the main reactor loop will keep creating new requests.

Is there a way to pause the main loop but have the fibers finish their execution?

Answer (score 1):

```
sleep 2
```

...

```
add_periodic_timer(0.001)
```

Are you serious?

Have you ever though how many `send_request`'s are sleeping in the loop? And it's adding 1000 every second.

What about this:

```
require 'eventmachine'
require 'em-http'
require 'fiber'

class Worker
  URL = 'http://example.com/api/whatever'

  def initialize callback
    @callback = callback
  end

  def work
    f = Fiber.current
    loop do
      http = EventMachine::HttpRequest.new(URL).get :timeout => 20

      http.callback do
        @callback.call http.response
        f.resume
      end
      http.errback do
        f.resume
      end

      Fiber.yield
    end
  end
end

def display(value)
  puts "Done: #{value.size}"
end

EventMachine.run do
  8.times do
    Fiber.new do
      Worker.new(method(:display)).work
    end.resume
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  It's possible that I wasn't clear enough.  I am using add_periodic_timer in the example in order to simulate the amount of messages I am receiving.  

The actual code is connected to rabbitmq with subscribe. AFAIK I am not able to throttle recieving the messages on the consumer side. That is the reason I decided that it to limit my consumer with a pool of workers and pause the main reactor loop when the workers are busy.

Since my consumer runs as a daemon, simply doing '8.times do' will not solve my problem as there will be an infinite amount of messages.